# Why is this QCQP non-convex?

Tags: optimization, convex-analysis, convex-optimization, non-convex-optimization, qcqp

Why is the following QCQP *non*-convex?

$$\begin{array}{ll} \underset{x,y \in \Bbb R}{\text{minimize}} & (x+2)^2 + (y+2)^2\\ \text{subject to} & x y \ge 4\\ & x \le 4\\ & y \ge 2\end{array}$$

The objective function is convex and the set of feasible solutions is also convex (follows from the graph).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is not convex because it is not written as $\min \{ f(x) : g_i(x) \leq 0, i=1,2,\ldots,m \}$ where $f$ and $g_i$ are convex functions.

The feasible region is convex as you point out. You can obtain a convex formulation by applying a logarithmic transformation to the nonconvex constraint: $\log x + \log y \geq \log 4$. This constraint implicitly restricts $x$ and $y$ to positive reals, which looking at the other constraints does not reduce the feasible region.

Comment: I am absolutely confused, each of you says something different. So the first question is what is the definition of a convex problem? The objective function is required to be convex (in a minimalize case as we have) and then? How are requirements for the constraints?

Comment: @dena The constraints are to be defined by convex functions. Siong Thye Goh is mistaken, this is the only correct answer.

Comment: What about this? https://www.sciencedirect.com/topics/mathematics/convex-programming-problem The table "Convex programming problem. f(x) is convex over the convex feasible set S." This is our case.

Comment: @dena you could use that definition, but then you need to phrase your problem in that way: $\min\{ f(x) : x \in S\}$ with $S = \ldots$. the KKT conditions then should be phrased in terms of the set $S$. For the first order condition, you need the subgradient of the convex indicator function ($\delta(x) = 0$ when $x \in S$, $\delta(x)=\infty$ otherwise). That is not an easy route.

Comment: @dena I just read the book that contains the table, and it's shockingly wrong. Be careful what you use as a resource.

Comment: I have seen something like this more times, even in other sources... That is why I thought that convex programming is if the feasible set is convex or if all the constraints function are convex. In this case I was confused because the feasible set is convex, but it is not true that all functions are convex $4-xy$ is not. And I was thinking so it is or not convex....Anyway, i see that you understand it and the right answer is that the functions must be convex, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Obviously, the objective function and the last two constraints are convex (quadratic, linear, linear respectively). If we look at the first constraint and transform it into the standard form as $-xy+4\leq0.$

The Hessian is

$\begin{bmatrix}0 & -1\\-1 & 0\end{bmatrix},$

which gives eigenvalues of -1 and 1, thus the Hessian is not positive semi-definite and the constraint is not convex. Combining all these facts, the optimization problem is not convex.

Comment: The eigenvalues of $\begin{bmatrix} 0 & -1 \\ -1 & 0 \end{bmatrix}$ are $\{-1, 1\}$.

Comment: You are correct. I made a mistake.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with you that a convex optimization problem is an optimization problem in which the objective function is a convex function and the feasible set is a convex set (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convex_optimization). The point is that this convex problem is not in standard form. We may express this convex problem in standard form as follows:
\begin{align*}
 &\min_{x, y \in \mathbb{R}} ~ (x + 2)^2 + (y + 2)^2\\
 &\mathrm{s.t.} \quad 0 \le x \le 4,\\
 &\qquad\,\, y \ge 2,\\
 &\qquad \sqrt{xy} \ge 2.
\end{align*}
*Note*: We did not change the feasible set.